Modulate tone of old mechanical buzzer
I have this old buzzer - and I am wondering if it is possible to hook up an arduino to modulate the frequency, to essentially play a tune ... Say, the Imperial March from Star Wars ...
Right now I think it is just hooked up to a DC source and gives off one tone.
Here it is:
![Buzzer 1]


modify the buzzer into a relay

you will get some frequency variation just by adjusting the voltage

You can model the buzzer as a loudspeaker that really, really wants to vibrate at one single frequency, by design. That is, it is a self-excited oscillator with a tightly-defined resonance.
You can make it vibrate at frequencies less than resonance simply by driving it at frequencies less than resonance, just like any loudspeaker.
You can also make it vibrate at frequencies above resonance by forcing it with a driving function that increases in amplitude with increasing frequency, to artificially "flatten" its response curve. Bose 901 loudspeakers work on that principle.
But this means driving the buzzer not with DC but with an AC signal small enough to not invoke the "chopping function" performed by the contact switch built into the buzzer. With the chopper switch defeated, the buzzer can be accurately modeled as a loudspeaker, about which lots of written material is available on the web.

That's a clever idea - thank you!
Part of the attraction would be to use the original disc to make the sound.


The buzzer is electro-mechanical. When powered up the coil is energised and that magnetises the steel core forming an electro-magnet.
The electromagnet pulls in the  brown disk in the photo. There will be a ferrous "pole piece" on the underside for this to work.
Pulling in the pole piece will cause the contact disk in the centre of the brown disc to move away from the contact screw, breaking the circuit, switching off the electromagnet and causing the disc to return to its initial position.

You may be able to adjust the frequency a little by adjusting the screw - open the locknut first - but don't expect too much.
To raise the pitch by an octave you would need to double the frequency of oscillation. Each semitone (there are twelve in the chromatic scale) would require a frequency increase of $ ^{12}\sqrt 2 $.
If your experiments with manual adjustment don't cause you to give up your dream then you could use a stepper motor to adjust the screw.
Once you've given up on that, just use the stepper motor to play music.
See Star Wars Imperial March - Stepper Motor Music - 4 Stepper Motor Organ playing MIDI Files on YouTube. Music? It depends on your definition.

The stepper motor version isn't bad ... :)
